# Django ModelForm - Allowing adds for ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, modelform

I'm trying to mimic the functionality from the Django Admin tool where it allows you to add objects for foreign keys (a little plus icon next to a dropdown). For example, let's say I have the following:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
```

When I go to add my first Blog using a ModelForm for Blog, it shows a dropdown next to Author. However, I have no Authors in the system so that dropdown is empty. In the admin tool, I believe it puts a little "+" icon next to the dropdown so you can quickly and efficiently add a record to the dropdown by opening up a popup.

That is extremely useful, and so I'd like to mimic it in my own app using ModelForms. Is that also built into Django's ModelForms? If so, how do I use it? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: That's the default behavior for a model with a ForeignKey field in Django admin. I don't believe there's any documentation specifically around how the link to add a related model is created.

Comment: I see that my question may have been a bit unclear, so I have updated it. I'm basically looking to mimic the Django admin's behavior in my own app using ModelForms, and was wondering if there was some way to do it that was built in without requiring me to code that behavior manually. Are you saying there is no way to do it without custom coding?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it would require custom coding, but it wouldn't be very difficult to mimic. All they're doing is opening a popup widow, creating the record and then executing a callback on the parent window from the child window via JavaScript to update the select with the new value(s).

Comment: I would very much like to upvote this question but I shall wait until an answer that provides a solution is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to work with: django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper

This post certainly will guide you:

[Django admin - How can I add the green plus sign for Many-to-many Field in custom admin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692822/django-admin-how-can-i-add-the-green-plus-sign-for-many-to-many-field-in-custo)